# 500 Internal Server Error in php for report extracting

Tags: php, phpexcel, internal-server-error

I am extracting report in excel format, For that I am using **PHPEXCEl** When I apply some filter to extract report it works fine but when try to extract report without any filter then I get the below error message. number of records are above 40000.

> "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error -

I have tried `ini_set("memory_limit","256M");` 
but still its giving the same error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May be the script is getting timed out.

Comment: Yea may be script is getting time out but how to solve this problem...? do you have any idea about this?

Comment: What does your error log say ?

Comment: Where Can I see my error logs??

Comment: If you are on linux : `cat /var/log/apache2/error_log` (debian), `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log` (ubuntu). It can depend on your VirtualHost configuration too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade `max_execution_time = 6000` in php.ini after check your server status

Comment: You maybe have some issue server side. The communication with your service doesn't work well. But the reason is not unique. Does the server works? Is it reachable?

Comment: It's working fine on my local server with same data.

Comment: So your local server works and its settings are good. But you have to check if you can reach the real server. Have you got any log?

Comment: Server log gives error : Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded in /var/www/erp/PHPExcel/Style/Color.php

Comment: some times it gives error : PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 79 bytes)

Comment: This is a strange error... First of all set this parameter in your php.ini: max_input_time = -1 (this is to correct "Maximum execution time of 0 seconds.." error)

Comment: Tried this one : max_input_time = -1

Comment: Same errors? Have you tried to view if your local php parameters are similar to server parameters? I think the fix is in it!

Comment: Now its giving error : HP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of -1 seconds exceeded in /var/www/erp/PHPExcel/Style.php on line 645

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121690/discussion-between-tejas-khutale-and-dave-m).